# Exposing a Private Variable using a Property to a Custom Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to create a custom editor unity script.

I need to access a private variable that I have exposed via property.

However, the property is not accessible using the Editor script.

I am trying to access the `MyObjects` property in the custom editor.

My Class

```
public class MySpecialClass : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] myObjects;
    public GameObject[] MyObjects {
        get {
            return myObjects;
        }

        set {
            myObjects = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My Custom Editor script

```
using UnityEditor;
[CustomEditor(typeof(MySpecialClass))]
public class MySpecialClassEditor : Editor {

    private bool[] showMyObjectSlots = new bool[MySpecialClass.MyObjects.Length]; 
}
```

***Why wouldn't a public property be accessible in to the CustomEditor?***

Comment: I am trying to access the `MyObjects` property in the custom editor.

Comment: You are trying to access MyObjects in a static context but MyObjects is not static

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance to access the non-static `MyObjects` property. The instance can be found through the [`target` field](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-target.html) in your custom editor. The field `target` is of type `UnityEngine.Object`, but it points to an object of the type of the `MonoBehaviour` of which the class is a custom editor (the argument in the `CustomEditor` attribute), and hence can be casted to it.